# db2 SYSIBM tables in oracle

Tags: oracle, db2, migrating

please, has anyone an idea, how could be this db2 statement rewritten into oracle database?

```
SELECT * 
FROM SYSIBM.SYSPLANDEP 
WHERE BNAME = 'TABLE1' 
  AND DNAME = 'PLAN1'
```

I think the oracle table could be ALL_DEPENDENCIES, but I don't know which are the corresponding columns for BNAME and DNAME

Comment: Its actually two different tables `SYS.ALL_DEPENDENCIES` and `SYS.PLAN`, if that's what you are looking for. But there is no relation between these two table i.e. you cannot possibly join them. Read more about `SYS` tables here - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21644/systemtables.htm#CIAFFECJ. `ALL_DEPENDENCIES` is the only table that can correspond to your need but I am not sure what `Dependencies of plan` means in terms of Oracle.